# how to save coordinates in db with comments when click on div and show according to coordinates in div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysqli

**What i need?**
I am using PHP. I have a div when user click on div it will shows textarea based on coordinates then user type some text bla bla bla and press save it close and saves into database with coordinates and text and display pointer/bullet on exact coordinates when user mouse hover on pointer/bullet it shows that text bla bla bla. This is i need.

**I try this**

**CSS**

```
#ClickBox {
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#2f2f2f;
    top:50px;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 12px Arial;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "ClickBox" style = "left:100px;"> </div>
```

**jQuery/JS**

```
$( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e){
    var coordX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        coordY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    alert( coordX + ' , ' + coordY );
});
```

[here is the fiddle of this code](http://jsfiddle.net/T8H9X/)

Comment: What is the actual thing you need help with?  Your existing code works, so what is the problem?

Comment: instead of alert I want to save these pointers in database with some additional information regarding this pointer. have you read what i need is ?

Comment: Are you asking for help explaining the process, what technologies to use, how to open the textarea mentioned above?  Your question is very broad.

Comment: I am using PHP i update my question. yes i am supposing someone help me.

Comment: You will need to display a text box in the correct spot, and after some event, use AJAX to send the data to a server endpoint, and then use some library to store it in a database.  If you need more help, ask a more specific question.

Comment: i thought you will provide code. if you can please. this is first time i am doing type thing so i need guideline with code. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94894/discussion-between-muddasir-abbas-and-tbwill4321).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**here is the solution finally done it.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Box</title>
<style type="text/css">
#ClickBox {
    width:640px;
    height:480px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#2f2f2f;
    top:50px;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 12px Arial;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    left:100px;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="ClickBox">
  <?php foreach($boxes as $box){ ?>
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo $box['note']; ?>"> <span style="position:absolute;left:<?php echo $box['position_left']; ?>px;top:<?php echo $box['position_top']; ?>px;background-color:#fff;width:10px;height:10px;"></span> </a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e){
    var coordX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        coordY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
        var note = window.prompt("Please Enter Note","Your Note Will Comes Here");
        var values = {coordX:coordX,coordY:coordY,note:note}; 
        var controller = 'box';
        var base_url = '<?php echo site_url(); ?>';
        var  myurl = base_url + controller + '/add_note/';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myurl,
            data: values,
            complete: function (data) {
                $('#ClickBox').empty().html(data.responseText);
            }
        });


});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery/JS**

```
$( '#ClickBox' ).click( function(e){
    var coordX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left,
        coordY = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'save.php',
       data: {
         x: coordX,
         y: coordY,
         otherData: 'otherData'
       },
       success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
       },
       dataType: 'text'
   });
});
```

you will need to create or update the target.  In this case I am using a **save.php** file.  I use PDO, you will need to update the DB connection accordingly.

**save.php**

```
<?php

if(intval($_POST['x']) > 0 && intval($_POST['y']) > 0 ) {

    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    $dbSave = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO coords (xCord, yCord, other) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
    $dbSave->execute(array($_POST['x'], $_POST['y'], $_POST['otherData']));
    // check for any errors when saving
    if($dbh->errorInfo() == '00000') {
        echo 'Success: ', $_POST['x'], ', ', $_POST['y'];
    } else {
        echo 'Error';
    }
} else  {
  echo 'Invalid Data';
}

?>
```